# Defining parameters for the bottom level in an intermediate level in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

Should parameters defined within a subcircuit pass to a lower level subcircuit in LTspice? If I define the parameters of the bottom level in the top level (or directly in the bottom level) everything works fine, but if I define those parameters in the intermediate level they do not pass to the lower.
Below a simple(!) example. Simple1 and simple2 are subcircuits; simple is the main schematic. If I define .param a=2 in simple or in simple 2 everything works fine. If I define it in simple1 I get the error: Can't resolve .param r=2*a

[image]

Comment: You can specify parameters and their default values on the SUBCKT line, itself. X cards can then invoke those SUBCKTs and, if they want to, over-ride those parameter values (and provide more, if they desire.) If you are writing an intermediate SUBCKT which has parameters passed to it and that it wants to pass along, it needs to specify those over-rides, explicitly, in the X card and it should enclose them in braces, {}. Does that answer your question? Or do you need concrete examples? If you need concrete examples, I'll want a concrete example from you to work from.

Comment: I don't need default values. I need to define some parameters of sub2 from sub1 schematic. If they are defined from main schematic they pass down until the bottom level. If they are defined at an intermediate level they don't go on.

Comment: I'd like to see the LTspice error logs. A lot can be adduced from that. There are ways to do most things. Spice itself has had many decades of development and LTspice exposes, so far as I'm aware, all of the tools available in Spice.

Comment: Just FYI: Read through this [discussion](https://forum.digikey.com/t/making-sub-circuits-hierarchical-circuits-in-ltspice/2038) about creating subcircuits. Then this [page](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Nested_Hierarchical_Models_for_the_Missing_Parts) for some discussion regarding ".param" values.